# Simulate multiple domains with rollup-plugin-dev

Tags: widget, rollupjs

I am trying to setup a dev environment for developing widgets. In the book [Third Party JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290548) They describe how to simulate multiple domains by modifying your hosts file and configuring Apache web server to create two virtual hosts. I was wondering if something similar is possible using the [rollup-plugin-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-dev) development server which uses the [fastify-http-proxy](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-http-proxy).

Rollup Config:

```js
...
  const devPlugin: Plugin = dev({
    dirs: ['dev'],
    port: 5000,
    // How to configure this? 
    proxy: []
  });
...
```

Basically I want to serve the widget IIFE code from one domain, say `widget.dev` and a test html file which loads the script code on another domain, say `publisher.dev`. The HTML page at publisher.dev would have a `<script>` tag which loads the widget:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Widget Test Page</title>
    <link href="/widget.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script async src="http://widget.dev"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="widget" data-border></div>
    <script>
      window.widget = {
        // widget config...
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem for development is to serve up your widget on some port and then create a separate project that will reach out to grab the js files. I created a separate react app that loaded the script files from the port they are served on. So to keep it extremely simple, in my `App.js` file of the dev host project I did something like this:

App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


export const loadScript = (src, id, onError) => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.async = true;
  script.onerror = (e) => onError(e, 'script', 'could not load script');
  script.setAttribute('data-id', id);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
};

export const loadStyle = (href, id, onError) => {
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = href;
  link.rel="stylesheet";
  link.type="text/css";
  link.onerror = (e) => onError(e, 'link', 'could not load style');
  link.setAttribute('data-id', id);
  document.head.appendChild(link);
};

const App = () => {

// run this effect one time only
useEffect(() => {
  loadStyle('http://localhost:5100/myWidget.css', 'widget-style');
  loadScript('http://localhost:3001/myWidget.js', 'widget-id');

}, []);

// ...
};
```

Depending on your use case, there are (probably) better ways to achieve this.